# Android Accelerometer setup: can I get it to run only when button it pressed.

Tags: android, timer, accelerometer

I am using an Accelerometer in my application and I am wondering if I can make it the way that accelerometer is only activates for a certain amount of time after the user has pressed a start button. It should stops when user press the stop button. It will essentially work as a pedometer which is part of a bigger application. This is the code used to implement the accelerometer:-

```
SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    int sensorType = Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER;
    sensorManager.registerListener(sensorListener, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(sensorType),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

I have the code counting the steps which is:-

```
final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener()
{

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
    {
            if(event.values[2]<3)
            {
                counter ++;
            }
            else if(event.values[2]>5)
            {
                counter --;
                counter ++;

            }
            sensorData.setText("Steps = "+ counter);

      }

      public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy){}
      };
```

I'm just wondering that since I'm counting the steps in the onSensorChanged method how do I limit this to only a button press state? Would it be possible to add a timer in to count how long has passed between the two button presses I mentioned earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.

Prepare manager:

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
```

Start accelerometer:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mAccelerometer, 
     SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
```

Stop:

```
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
```

Don't forget unregister listener in onPause() method.

Comment: ahh i see so the start accelerometer would go in the onclick for my start button and the stop would go in the stop.  have any ideas what i could do with for a way of timing the session?

Comment: You want miasure time between start and stop? Use System.currentTimeMillis().